# paste data after last row from api via url with data google script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I reopen the question because the solution doesn't work.
When I extract information from Matomo with an API, an analytical tool according to time periods. I need that every time I extract the data with different dates, it doesn't overwrite the data and paste it in the last row with data.

The problem is that as the info is extracted through the api, a spreadsheet from which to copy the data is not generated. I don't know how to put in code that is copied in lastrow with data

```js
function Entrada() {        
  var csvUrl = "https://matomo.jccm.es/index.php?date=2022-07-01,today&filter_limit=-1&format=CSV&format_metrics=1&idSite=152&language=es&method=Actions.getEntryPageUrls&module=API&period=day&flat=1&token_auth=xxxx&translateColumnNames=1&convertToUnicode=0";
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Páginas');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: Did you try something like `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, ...`?

Comment: @johndee31415, It's working! but the first row is the column definitions, how can I select the csvData range except the first row?

I do not know how to select the range of the API because it is not in any spreadsheet, Thanks for everything I am new on this

Comment: `Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent).slice(1)` should do the trick

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This isn't a "question reopen", it's question repost. To properly "reopen" a question, edit your previous question and briefly describe why the answers in the linked question didn't work in your case.